# Graph of zero point clumped together after applying ggbreak() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggbreak

I dont have data between  1 and 11 hrs (in`your text` x axis) so I want to delete this portion from my graph.

How can I put zero values in each group instead of being clumped together?

[image]

I tried to plot the graph as follows:

```
plot <-  ggplot(bgse_lmean, aes(time_h)) + 
          geom_point(aes(y = Conc, shape = Isolate, col = Isolate, group = Isolate), size = 2.5)+
           geom_line(aes(y = Conc, group= Isolate, col = Isolate))+ 
          scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,12, 16, 20, 24))+
           xlab("Time (h)") + ylab("Conc mg/ml") + 
          scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
          facet_wrap(parameters~., 
           strip.position =  "top", 
          nrow = 3)

plot
p2 <- plot + scale_x_break(c(1,11))
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a small reproducible example with `dput` i.e. `dput(head(bgse_lmean, 20))`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.